# Ubuntu 14.04 Unknown Display, nvidia graphics

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, display, fonts

I tried the @Golboth solution in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139947/why-cant-ubuntu-12-04-detect-my-screen-resolution/493135#493135). Worked sometimes, it has an intermittent behavior, sometimes work, most of times doesn't work. Installed Nvidia drivers, Ubuntu detects the Graphics : Intel® Ivybridge Desktop, but in the System Settings, in Display section still appears the Unknown Display. The question is from 2012 year, my monitor is a LG Led 20EN33 (Analog) model. My Ubuntu is 14.04, tried too the

xrandr --newmode $(cvt 1920 1080 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1920x1080/')

solution, worked, adapted to the LG screen resolution parameters, but the rendering fonts are not clear, it's like a 1998 year rendering fonts same as with no Cristal Clear... Any suggest would be appreciate, Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

**Please check to make sure your monitor is plugged in fully, I noticed my monitor VGA cord was loose, I tightened it, and now it can detect the monitor.**

If that's not the case, then you can add it through command line with instruction below.

---

I've yet to find a proper solution but I have a pattern that seems to work for me.

In terminal enter the following:

> cvt 1920 1080

This command will give you the calculated parameters of your screen.
Copy everything after the pound sign and paste it into the next line

> xrandr --newmode "Copied Line from above"

My personal calculations:

> xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

This command will add the new mode to your list of options

Type `xrandr -q` to list your screen outputs and look for your connected screen eg. VGA1, HDMI1 or DP1

Finally add the mode to the problem monitor.

> xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.00

Comment: Thanks for your last comment! I tried to solve my monitor issue for days, until I read yours. Yes, it simply caused by a loose connection.

Comment: These commands work, but whenever the computer is turned off,  the 1920x1080 is not recorded. Is there a way such that I don't have to run these commands every time I turn my computer on?